# MySQL change "select where id in select" to some kind of join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Situation:

I have a table "trips" with tourist trips

```
tripid    country   city
1         UK        London
2         US        New York
3         US        Las Vegas
```

And I have a table "prices" with prices

```
tripid   price      duration
1        200        8
1        400        10
1        600        12
2        300        5
2        900        15
3        50         10
3        150        30
```

Now let's say I want to have all trips in the US with a price between 50 and 200

Then I use this SQL query:

```
SELECT trip.* FROM `trips` WHERE `country` = 'US' AND `tripid` in 
(SELECT tripid FROM `prices` WHERE `price` BETWEEN 50 and 200 GROUP BY tripid)
```

Of course this one is working well, but my table is growing and this is SLOWWW. This is because the sub-query is very inefficient.

What can I do to get this part out of it and make it faster?

Comment: Try it with exists `SELECT trip.* FROM trips WHERE country = 'US' AND EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM prices WHERE price  BETWEEN 50 and 200 AND prices.tripid=trip.tripid GROUP BY tripid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to join the prices rows in the result, use an `EXIST` clause:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM trips t
WHERE t.country = 'US' AND exists (select 1 FROM prices WHERE t.id = tripid AND price BETWEEN 50 and 200)
```

No need for any `GROUP` clause.

Comment: I think you're right. This is even faster than the "inner join & group by"!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an INNER JOIN here instead of a subselect:

```
SELECT trip.* FROM trips INNER JOIN prices USING (tripid)
WHERE price BETWEEN 50 AND 200 AND country='US' GROUP BY tripid
```

Make sure you have an index on `trips`.`country` for your WHERE clause on it, and it would probably also help to have an index on `prices`.`duration` for the BETWEEN clause.

Comment: This drasticly improves the loading time. Thanks!

Comment: @user2740744: please be aware that this is invalid SQL. Every other DBMS will reject this use of the `GROUP BY` clause. MySQL chooses to return random data instead (they call it indeterminate). Details here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: Thanks, I think Jon Hinsons answer below is better.